# How to display posts with a role defined according to the role of the user

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have posts and users to which I assign one or more roles. The roles are the same between users and posts so that I can compare them.

To assign roles, I use the [spatie/laravel-permissions](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) library.

I'm building an API. I use Laravel's resources.

I would like to be able to make posts with the "admin" role visible only to users who have the "admin" role.

Currently, I can't.

CategoryController

```
$categorie = Category::where('slug->' . auth()->user()->lang, $slug)
        ->with(['posts' => function ($query) {
            $query->published();
        }])->first();

return new CategoryResource($categorie);
```

My PostResource
class PostResource extends JsonResource

```
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'title' => $this->title,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'content' => $this->content,
            'image' => $this->image,
            'status' => $this->status,
            'date' => $this->date,
            'roles' => $this->roles
        ];
    }
}
```

My CategoryResource

```
class CategoryResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'   => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'posts' => PostResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('posts')),
            'count_posts' => $this->posts->where('status', 'published')->count(),
            //'has_new_posts' => $this->has_new_post
        ];
    }
}
```

**Is it possible to manage this directly via resources? Or via a eloquent query**

Personally, I had tried a different approach in the controller but I do not find it good and in addition I have an array instead of an object, which does not suit me.

```
$categorie = Category::where('slug->' . auth()->user()->lang, $slug)
        ->with(['posts' => function ($query) {
            $query->published();
        }])->first();

    $posts = $categorie->posts;

    $postsWithGoodRole = [];

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        if ($post->hasAnyRole(Auth::user()->roles)) {
            array_push($postsWithGoodRole, $post);
        }
    }


    return response()->json([
        'posts' => $posts
    ]);
```